# Removing unwanted links from a network graph

Tags: r, igraph

EDIT: thanks for giving feedback on the phrasing of my question. I have reworked my question with the assistance of igraph, thanks to John Coleman for his insight.

I have a table of points that are connected, like so:

```
+------+------+
| Col1 | Col2 |
+------+------+
| a    | b    |
| a    | c    |
| b    | c    |
| d    | c    |
| c    | e    |
| a    | d    |
| b    | d    |
| f    | e    |
| f    | g    |
| g    | h    |
| f    | h    |
| e    | g    |
+------+------+
```

I've plotted this in an igraph which gives this result:

[image]

Now I want to delete all vertices that link together closed groups of vertices. In the example graph, vertex "e" is the culprit. I want to delete it to get this:

[image]

My goal is to have only clusters of vertices that have distance 1 to all the vertices that they are connected to. They can have any degree, as long as there is no vertice with distance 2 to any other distance in the graph.

How would i go about recognizing and removing such vertices? I have so far written this code:

```
# current data
test_id <- data.frame(V1 = c("a","a","b","d","c","a","b","f","f","g","f","e"), V2 = c("c","b","c","c","e","d","d","e","g","h","h","g"), stringsAsFactors = F)
# wanted output data
test_id <- data.frame(V1 = c("a","a","b","d","a","b","f","g","f"), V2 = c("c","b","c","c","d","d","g","h","h"), stringsAsFactors = F)
mg <- graph.data.frame(test_id, directed = F)
mg_deg <- degree(mg)
mg_dis <- distances(mg)
plot(mg)
```

I'm quite new to igraph, so i don't know all it's functions yet. In pseudocode i would be looking for something like this:

```
for(n in unique(test_id)) {
  neighbours <- get_neighbours(n)
  if(any(not_connected(neighbours)) == TRUE) {
    test_id <- test_id[(test_id[,1] == n | test_id[,2] == n),]
  }
}
```

where "neighbours" mean specifically vertices with distance 1 (not more), and not_connected(neighbours) are neighbours that are not directly connected to eachother (so distance > 1)

Comment: My criterion can be summarized in one sentence: if an ID (1048) matches multiple other IDs (188, 752, 916, 1058), but some of those IDs do no match eachother (only 188 and 916 match), then all rows containing that ID (1048) must be deleted.

Comment: Example of an ID with good matching: If (256) matches two other IDs (695, 101) and they also match eachother (695 matches 101) then (256) is fine and can stay.

Comment: Sounds like a logic problem. Can you provide the algorithm that you're using to match records?

Comment: The criterion you specified seems graph-theoretic: a node is a cheater node if its degree is greater than 1 and it furthermore has distance 2 to at least one other node.

Comment: @JohnColeman thank you so much! I just started reading on graph theory and this describes exactly what i'm looking for. I'm fiddling with igraph now to see if that gets me the right info.

Comment: I have updated my question. This is where i'm at now, does it make sense?